# Open Stack Log Format

Tags: logging, openstack

I am trying to analyze the OpenStack log file having the following format:

**nova-api.log.1.2017-05-16_13:53:08    16-05-17    00:00.3 25746   INFO    nova.osapi_compute.wsgi.server  [req-9bc36dd9-91c5-4314-898a-47625eb93b09   113d3a99c3da401fbd62cc2caa5b96d2    54fadb412c4e40cdbaed9335e4c35a9e    -   -   -]  10.11.10.1  GET /v2/54fadb412c4e40cdbaed9335e4c35a9e/servers/detail HTTP/1.1    status: 200 len:    1893    time:   0.2577181**

Looking for a help to know the headers of every session in the above Log...Sorry, I am new to this area any suggestions will be really a great help...

Comment: How is this related to R programming?

Comment: Sorry, Removed the 'R' Tag...I am trying to analyze the Log using R...